# Hive - select multiple tables without join

Tags: hive

I have a table which only has one column "tgt_dt" and 10 records: date "2015-09-01", date "2015-02-01", date "2015-08-10", etc.

I need to use these dates as condition to choose from anther table. i.e, in sql, i can just do:

```
select T2.tgt_dt, A,B, C,sum(D) 
from TableA T1,
     TableB T2
where T1.date between T2.tgt_dt - 90 and T2.tgt_dt
group by T2.tgt_dt, A,B, C
```

What's the best way to do this in hive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just do a cartesian join here:

```
select T2.tgt_dt, A,B, C,sum(D) 
from 
     TableA T1
JOIN
     TableB T2
where T1.date between T2.tgt_dt - 90 and T2.tgt_dt
group by T2.tgt_dt, A,B, C
```

If you wanted a more efficient approach you could do something like:

```
select b.tgt_dt, A,B, C,sum(D) 
from 
     TableA T1
LATERAL VIEW explode(array('date1','date2','date3')) b as tgt_dt
where T1.date between b.tgt_dt - 90 and b.tgt_dt
group by b.tgt_dt, A,B, C
```

Comment: your first anwswer is pratically the same as my question, hive does not support unequal join, i believe

Comment: its not an unequal join, its a cartesian join, which hive should support.

Comment: you are right, my mistake, hive added "between" in later version, i forgot about that.